# Call a Sony 5100 as Client with SDK?

Tags: sdk, camera, sony

I want to develop a automated PhotoBot. The core of Development is written in PHP and JS like a WebApp. The SDK requires HTTP and JSON an both is supported by my WebApp but in the wrong way. I need to call multiple Camera and the App is controled by a tablet or computer so it is not possible to connect the tablet and the camera directly.

Is it possible or not?

Comment: Just to be sure I understand. Is your question can your camera to the tablet using the "Remote Camera API"? If that is the question then the answer is yes for the A5 5100 you can.   Here is the full list of supported devices: https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/device-support/

Comment: A5 and related cameras work only with SDK, if you install the Playmemories App from Sony, which is only available for Android and IOS. Windows App you can install only on Sony VAIO. So answer is App controlled by tablet (or smartphone) yes, by computer, only VAIO Laptop.
But if you go with a Lenscam like DSC-QX30 or a Actioncam (not good for photobox) it works without Playmemories as a proxy app